# How to install Java debugger for Emacs on MAC?

Tags: java, macos, debugging, emacs

UC berkeley offers a free java debugger called [gjdb](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~hilfingr/gjdb.html) which is a modified version of gdb. but I have trouble about how to install it. Specifically, in the README file it says:

---

### INSTALLATION

To configure, use

```
DIR/configure OPTIONS
```

in the directory in which you want to build, where DIR designates the 
directory in which you have unpacked the source (can be .).  Use

```
DIR/configure --help
```

to see the options.

Next, you can simply type

```
make
```

to build,

```
make install
```

to install, and

```
make install-doc
```

to compile and install the documentation file gjdb.pdf.

To use gjdb from Emacs, arrange to load it in your initialization
(.emacs) file with the command

```
(load "DIR/gjdb")
```

where DIR is the directory in which 'make install' put gjdb.el (see the 
output of configure --help), or just

```
(load "gjdb")
```

if you have put DIR on Emacs's load path.

---

I just have no Idea about the installation process.
If any of you have a better choice for a JAVA debugger in Emacs, please let me know!

Comment: Specifically, what part of the installation instructions are giving you trouble?

Comment: Actually it's the first step, I don't know which option after configure should I use, I've tried prefix==<aDirectoryIChoose> but after I press enter, it doesn't work

Comment: I'm not familiar with this codebase, but software that uses `configure` is generally designed with the most common settings as the default. What if you just run `./configure` without any options and keep going?

Comment: Thanks for reply! I've tried ./configure and returns a page of error which at the end said "can not find Java installation. " But I've the latest version of Java 8 as well as jdk.

Comment: Then you'll probably have to pass an argument saying where your JDK lives. If you run `./configure --help` do you see an argument that looks like it might do this, e.g. `--jdk` or `--java`?

Comment: Yeah! I successfully configure the installation after following your advice! Thank you sooooo much!! This has bothered me a whole weekend!

Comment: Great! Please consider adding an answer to your own question below, showing the actual `configure` command that got this working for you.

Answer (score 2):

thanks for the help of @chris, I've come up with the right way to configure.
just use

```
./configure apphome==/usr
```

everything goes as expected!!