# Error when try to install GJDB in ucb cs61b course lab

Tags: java, debugging, jdb

I am learning ucb course CS61b Spring 2014. I'm trying to finish the [lab7](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61b/lab/lab7/).

In this lab, it introduces us to *GJDB*, a Java debugger. After I downloaded the lasted version of GJDB (from [here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~hilfingr/gjdb/)), planned to build and install it by following the readme file given, I got an error.

> ### INSTALLATION
>
> To configure, use
>
> ```
> DIR/configure OPTIONS
> ```
>
> in the directory in which you want to build, where DIR designates the 
>   directory in which you have unpacked the source (can be .).  Use
>
> ```
> DIR/configure --help
> ```
>
> to see the options. Next, you can simply type
>
> ```
> make
> ```
>
> to build,
>
> ```
> make install
> ```
>
> to install, and
>
> ```
> make install-doc
> ```
>
> to compile and install the documentation file gjdb.pdf.
>
> To use gjdb from Emacs, arrange to load it in your initialization
>   (.emacs) file with the command
>
> ```
> (load "DIR/gjdb")
> ```
>
> where DIR is the directory in which 'make install' put gjdb.el (see
>   the  output of configure --help), or just
>
> ```
> (load "gjdb")
> ```
>
> if you have put DIR on Emacs's load path.

Everything is fine before I try to do `sudo make`, then I get an error in given code files.

```
/gjdb-6.4.1/src/ucb/gjdb/Env.java:15: error: package com.sun.tools.jdi is not visible
import com.sun.tools.jdi.*;
                    ^
(package com.sun.tools.jdi is declared in module jdk.jdi, which does not export it)
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
make: *** [src/gjdb.jar] Error 1
```

Here is a screenshopt of the place the error happens:

[image]

Has anyone had the same problem or have any suggestions to make `make` here run successfully? Or, is there an another way or any links to introduce about running gjdb correctly?

Comment: Hi, everyone. I think [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295882/how-to-install-java-debugger-for-emacs-on-mac?rq=1) is a relevant question. However, it seems the question owner didn't meet the problem I have.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say. My env is macOS Version 10.13.5. I try the jdk9.0.1, jdk1.8 and jdk1.7. They all give me the same error.

Comment: Try to use Java 8 or earlier, the error means that the source tries to use internal classes not accessible in Java 9 (or 10). It is not possible that Java 8 and 7 give the same error, given modules where only introduced in Java 9, so earlier versions don't have that error; that would mean you are still compiling with Java 9. In any case, ask your professor or tutor for support.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point. But I think I have already used the Java 8 and 7 because if I use the Java 9, when I `configure`, it will give me some errors: `Error: Unrecognized Java version: "java version "9.0.1"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)"`. I was using Java 8 when did `make`.